# "Paypal express checkout", not see any transactions in paypal account, although reture success code in program

Tags: php, paypal

Everything runs well, users are directed to paypal, commit the payment, and returns "SUCCESS" code and comes back to the merchant website. But when I log into the user account and merchant account, I can not see any transactions. None after several hours.

I am use 3nd party integration and sandbox testing. (I can send money directly from the sandbox accounts. )

Here are the strings.

```
METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout <p>
[VERSION] => 65.1 <p>
[PWD] => 13012.. <p>
[USER] => emily....<p>
[SIGNATURE] => AY-...<p>
[ADDRESSOVERRIDE] => 1 <p>
[L_NAME0] => 106791TBL3 <p>
[L_AMT0] => 18 <p>
[L_QTY0] => 1 <p>
[L_DESC0] => ...<p>
[MAXAMT] => 43 <p>
[AMT] => 18 <p>
[ITEMAMT] => 18<p> 
[CALLBACKTIMEOUT] => 4<p> 
[INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => false<p> 
[ReturnUrl] => https://.. <p>
[CANCELURL] => https://..<p>
[CURRENCYCODE] => USD <p>
[PAYMENTACTION] => sale<p>
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being thick (I'm not a PayPal expert), but is the purpose of a sandbox account not to - *not* generate any actual transactions?

Comment: The transaction should appear in the history column of the <bold>sandbox accounts</bold>, not in any real Paypal accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You should see transactions even in the sandbox environment, but you MUST log in as the test-merchant that you used in your settings, and you MUST log in in the sandbox environment.

Easiest way is to login with your developer account first, then list your test-accounts, select the merchant account and then click ad the end of the page "Enter sandbox site", that would give you a login prompt where you would enter the test-merchant password. If you don't know it, reset it from the developer site.

Answer (score 0):

Check a mail message sent by IPN service – it should contain the “TransactionID” field – the identifier of the successfully submitted transaction.